# How to access 'index' in *ngFor and edit it (can't delete more than one item in a list)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, indexing, ngfor

I have this:

HTML:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let object of objectList; let idx = index">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" text-left [(ngModel)]="objectList[idx].name" placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
            <ion-input type="text" text-right [(ngModel)]="objectList[idx].amount" placeholder="Amount"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="end">
            <ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteObject(object)">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

TS:

```
public deleteObject(object) {
    let index = this.objectList.indexOf(object);
    this.objectList.splice(index, 1);
}

public addObject() {
    this.objectList.push({'name': '', 'amount': ''});
}
```

When I add an `object` with the function `addObject()` (called when a button is clicked), an empty item appears on the screen and it is normal, but when I delete an item sliding it and clicking on delete button (that calls `deleteObject(object)` function) something strange happen. I can delete one item but if I try do delete another one, I can't slide any of the items. I thought the problem is the `index` in the `*ngFor` but I can't figure out how to manage it

Comment: Try `(click)="objectList.splice(idx, 1)"`.

Comment: If the problem is the index, you can change your `ngModel` approach to `[(ngModel)]="object.name"` since the `*ngFor` already give you this data.

Comment: try not to mutate you source, instead make a copy without the data you want to remove and reaffect variable, should work fine

Comment: try add "name" to the input < ion-input name="{{'name'+i}}" ....> < ion-input name="{{'ammount'+i}}" ....>  and/or use [(ngModel)]="object.name" and [ngModel)]="object.amount"

Comment: It's hard to know what is going on without being able to reproduce it. For example, I'm not sure I understand what "but if I try do delete another one, I can't slide any of the items" means. Is your delete button some sort of slider control? If you can reproduce your error on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use .filter or use another approach where you create a new object (array) for your list to prevent issues with splice, which mutates your original array and will mess your indexes.

Here is a possible implementation:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qz5zfx

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let object of objectList; let idx = index">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" text-left [(ngModel)]="objectList[idx].name" placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
            <ion-input type="text" text-right [(ngModel)]="objectList[idx].amount" placeholder="Amount"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="end">
            <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteObject(idx)">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button block color="primary" (click)="addObject()">
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon> Add Item
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  objectList = [
    { name: "item1", amount: 1 },
    { name: "item2", amount: 2 },
    { name: "item3", amount: 3 },
    { name: "item4", amount: 4 },
    { name: "item5", amount: 5 },
  ]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  public deleteObject(objectIndex) {
    this.objectList = this.objectList.filter( (item, index) => {
      if (index !== objectIndex) return true;
    })
}

  public addObject() {
      this.objectList.push({ name: 'newItem', amount: 25 });
  }

}
```

When you use filter method it creates a new array, which you can assign back to your objectList, this way you are not mutating your objectList but override it with new array, which angular's change detection will use to "re-draw your list and reassign indexes.

UPDATE for IONIC4:

Ionic 4 requires you to call specific method to close sliding items before items deletion: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15486#issuecomment-419924318

So the template code should be:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list #dynamicList>
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let object of objectList; let idx = index">
            <ion-item>
                {{ object.name }}
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options side="end">
                <ion-button color="danger" (click)="dynamicList.closeSlidingItems(); deleteObject(idx)">
                    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
            </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-button block color="primary" (click)="addObject()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon> Add Item
      </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because your idea seems to work, but not completely. For some reasons it doesn't work in a ionic 4 project. I've just created a ionic 4 and a ionic 3 project, I've copied-pasted your code in them and: in ionic 3 project it works, in the ionic 4 one the problem is still there

Comment: Doing tests I wrote `(click)="deleteObject(idx-1)"`. So with the code you wrote and adding `-1` it "works" but obviously I delete the previous item in the list. This method allow me to delete more than one item (even if it is not the right one). And I can't understand why

Comment: I will create dummy code in ionic 4 and will check it

Comment: I hope you will do it as soon as possible

Comment: doing now;) 15 min

Comment: so what doesn't work for you? sliding items stops sliding?

Comment: I have updated my answer, tested this works with Ionic 4